# How Can I Model Many Short Time Series Samples?

Tags: statistics, time-series

How Can I Model Multiple Short Time Series Samples?

For example, let's say I have a new subject each month, and I measure each subject every day for the entire month. I then want to model these multiple strings of independent time series because I assume that there is an underlying pattern that applies to all 12 subjects. However, a time series with an n of 30 is too short to model, so is there some way to group these 12 time series together for a parallel analysis?

I imagine the way to handle this is similar to how one might handle a time series with multiple breaks of unknown length. Unfortunately, I unaware of how to deal with this type of data structure.

Any thoughts on where to even begin? What terms I should research?

Answer (score 0):

Well. Depends on what you're interested in. Makes it a lot easier if we know what kind of data you have, and what you're trying to analyse.

Trying to answer your question: If you assume that there is some underlying structure which is homogenous for, say, 6 of the subjects, and different for the other half, you can just pool the two data sets and do some kind of group-mean analysis. If you're interested in a temporal change over the 12 months, then you need to assume that each subject are homogenous across whatever variable you're measuring.

Normally, for e.g. timeseries in economics, what you're describing is called "censored" or "truncated data".

If we want to measure the income of everyone in a country, we do this by checking electronic paychecks or something. But some people at the end of each tail, may not have a visible income. Poor people may be earning income in other ways, and rich people may want to hide some of their income. This is censored data, and any advanced timeseries stats book will have something on that.

Truncated data is similar. Just imagine income again. If we truncate everyone who makes < 10,000$ a year, then this will "cut off the end" of your distribution. There are also remedies for this. Again check an advanced time series book.

Hope this helped a bit.